# ActiveRecord poly Appended Array vs Concatenated Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord

Why does the connections table get updated when I call @user.connections for the following?

Connection Model

```
class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :left_nodeable, :polymorphic => true
    belongs_to :right_nodeable, :polymorphic => true

    # Statuses:
    PENDING  = 0    
    ACCEPTED = 1

    named_scope :pending,  :conditions => { :connection_status => PENDING }
    named_scope :accepted,  :conditions => { :connection_status => ACCEPTED }
end
```

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :left_connections, :as => :left_nodeable, :class_name => 'Connection', :conditions => {:left_nodeable_type => 'User', :right_nodeable_type => 'User'}
    has_many :right_connections, :as => :right_nodeable, :class_name => 'Connection', :conditions => {:right_nodeable_type => 'User', :left_nodeable_type => 'User'}

    def connections
        self.left_connections << self.right_connections
    end
end
```

If I use:

```
    def connections
        self.left_connections + self.right_connections
    end
```

Then the model works ok but I cannot use any of my named_scope methods.

So I guess my questions boils down to...

What is the difference between the "<<" and "+" operator on an ActiveRecord?  Why does using "<<" change the database, and using "+" cause named_scope methods to fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model is updated because left_connections is updated with the `<<` method. This makes left_connections = left_connections + right_connections.

```
arr = [1,2]
arr << [3,4]
arr #=> [1,2,3,4]
-------------------------
arr = [1,2]
arr + [3,4] #=> [1,2,3,4]
arr #=> [1,2]
```

`self.left_connections + self.right_connections` is the correct way to return a concatenation.  As for your named_scope methods, I couldn't tell you why they're failing without seeing them.

Comment: Thanks Garrett.  I've updated the question with some named scopes that fail in the connection model.  So the remaining question would be "how do I call @user.connections.pending ?

Comment: Ah, so the problem is .connections() returns an array, and you can't use a scope on an array. You could instead call `@user.connections.reject{ |c| c.connection_status == ACCEPTED }`

Comment: or you can create a connection class method/scope `self.with_user(user_id)` that returns `where("user_id = ?", user_id)` and then chain them (e.g. `Connection.with_user(@user.id).pending`).  Sorry for the rails 3 syntax, but it's been a while since I've used rails 2 queries